# Can’t clear my TweenMax preload animation after it finishes so I can’t access my website? How do I resolve this?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am new to TweenMax and as the title suggests I am using it for a preload animation before actually accessing my website. Currently the preload does its' animation but once it finishes it doesn't clear/hide itself to reveal the website and I'm not sure how to resolve this issue?
I'll appreciate it if any one can give us a helping hand.
Here's some of my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Website for an upcoming RnB Singer.">
    <meta name="author" content="Dominic Robeson">

    <title>Vix Sambi | Offical Website</title>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat+Brush" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/stylish-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--JQuery/JS-->
        <script   src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- ====== PRELOADER ====== -->

    <div class="preloader">
      <img class="logo-svg" src="img/logo2.svg" />
    </div>

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class='navbar-toggle' title='Menu'>
            <div class='bar1'></div>
            <div class='bar2'></div>
            <div class='bar3'></div>
        </div>

        <nav class="nav-hide">


        <ul>
            <li><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#songs">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#video">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="#me">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pics">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Latnews">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Header -->
        <header id="top" class="header">
            <a href="#top"><img class="logo" src="img/logo2.svg"></a>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                 </div>
            </div>

        </header>
```

Heres the javascript for the preload animation:

```
  <script>
    var tl = new TimelineMax({
  repeat: 2
});

tl.add(
  TweenMax.from(".logo-svg", 2, {
    scale: 0.5,
    rotation: 360,
    ease: Elastic.easeInOut
  })
);

tl.add(
  TweenMax.to(".logo-svg", 2, {
    scale: 0.5,
    rotation: 360,
    ease: Elastic.easeInOut
  })
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an 'onComplete' callback to hide it when it is complete.

```
<script>
    var tl = new TimelineMax({
  repeat: 2, 
    onComplete : function () {
       // example hide the target 
        this._last.target[0].style.display = 'none'; 
       // example hide the target parent node 
        this._last.target[0].parentNode.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
});

tl.add(
  TweenMax.from(".logo-svg", 2, {
    scale: 0.5,
    rotation: 360,
    ease: Elastic.easeInOut
  })
);

tl.add(
  TweenMax.to(".logo-svg", 2, {
    scale: 0.5,
    rotation: 360,
    ease: Elastic.easeInOut
  })
);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! Yeah that gets rid of the svg but Im still left with the background colour for it so im guessing I have to do some :before/:after in the css for it?  This is my CSS code for the preloader:                    .preloader{
  position: fixed;
  background: #222;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.logo-svg{
  position: relative;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin: -75px 0px 0px -75px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1001;
}

Comment: If you send me the link , I can do it for you no problem

Comment: I have updated the code example which should also hide the preloader div, but again - The concept of implementing this should work for anything. You just need to decide what you need to do after if completes